# Reactjs convert class components to functional components

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am new in react. I want to use form stepper in my project. I found one library but in that library using class components. I am little confuse convert class components to functional components. I have short knowledge of react.

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Stepper from 'react-stepper-horizontal'
import { Card } from 'reactstrap'
import GeneralForm from './../../components/con/GeneralForm'
import PersonalDetailsForm from './../../components/con/PersonalDetailsForm'
import NomineeDetailsForm from './../../components/con/NomineeDetailsForm'

const ConCreate = (props) => {


  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.nextPage = this.nextPage.bind(this);
    this.previousPage = this.previousPage.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      page: 0,
      steps: [
        {title: 'Visitor Details'},
        {title: 'Personal Details'},
        {title: 'Nominee Details'}
      ]
    };
  }

  nextPage() {
    this.setState({ page: this.state.page + 1 });
  }

  previousPage() {
    this.setState({ page: this.state.page - 1 });
  }




  return (

    <Card>
       <Stepper steps={ steps } activeStep={ page } />
         {page === 0 && <GeneralForm onSubmit={nextPage} />}
         {page === 1 && (
       <PersonalDetailsForm
       previousPage={previousPage}
       onSubmit={nextPage}
       />
       )}
       {page === 2 && (
       <NomineeDetailsForm
       previousPage={previousPage}
       onSubmit={onSubmit}
       />
       )}
     </Card>
  )
}

ConCreate.propTypes = {

}

const mapDispatchToProps = {}

function mapStateToProps (state) {

}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ConCreate)
```

How can I convert below code in functional components

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.nextPage = this.nextPage.bind(this);
    this.previousPage = this.previousPage.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      page: 0,
      steps: [
        {title: 'Visitor Details'},
        {title: 'Personal Details'},
        {title: 'Nominee Details'}
      ]
    };
  }

  nextPage() {
    this.setState({ page: this.state.page + 1 });
  }

  previousPage() {
    this.setState({ page: this.state.page - 1 });
  }
```

Please suggest me how to convert class components to functional components.

Comment: You have to use ```useState```  from react to manage your states so you don't need to declare the constructor in the class. Doing that you will not need class and function will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the code below:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Stepper from 'react-stepper-horizontal'
import { Card } from 'reactstrap'

import GeneralForm from './../../components/con/GeneralForm'
import PersonalDetailsForm from './../../components/con/PersonalDetailsForm'
import NomineeDetailsForm from './../../components/con/NomineeDetailsForm'

const ConCreate = (props) => {

  const initStepsValue = [
    {title: 'Visitor Details'},
    {title: 'Personal Details'},
    {title: 'Nominee Details'}
  ]

  const [page, setPage] = useState(0)
  const [steps, setSteps] = useState(initStepValue)

  const nextPage = () => setPage(page + 1) 
  const prevPage = () => previousPage(page - 1)


  return (
    <Card>
       <Stepper steps={ steps } activeStep={ page } />
         {page === 0 && <GeneralForm onSubmit={nextPage} />}
         {page === 1 && (
           <PersonalDetailsForm
             previousPage={previousPage}
             onSubmit={nextPage}
           />
         )}
         {page === 2 && (
           <NomineeDetailsForm
             previousPage={previousPage}
             onSubmit={onSubmit}
           />
         )}
     </Card>
  )
}

ConCreate.propTypes = {}

const mapDispatchToProps = {}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({})

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ConCreate)
```

Answer (score 1):

Functional components do not use state like a class. You can use the useState method with a functional component though. But to answer your question.

```
  class MyClassComponent extends Component {
     render() {
      return(
       // code
    )
   }      
 }
    export default MyClassComponent;
```

Here is a functional component

```
function MyFunctionalComponent() {
    return(
    //code
  )
}
export default MyFunctionalComponent;
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your constructor and functions with this code, basically you don't need a constructor and 'this'.

```js
const [page, setPage] = React.useState(0);
const [steps, setSteps] = React.useState([ 
        {title: 'Visitor Details'},
        {title: 'Personal Details'},
        {title: 'Nominee Details'}
        ])

function nextPage() {
    setPage(page + 1)
  }

function previousPage() {
    setPage(page - 1)
}
```