# ReactJS Invalid Hook call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am currently working on learning ReactJS and followed a tutorial that helped me with a decent start on using firebase with authentication and authorization for a webpage. Now I am using a Sign-In page template from material-ui and trying to get it merged in with my current code. I have no problem getting the Grids and such to display, but I can't get the styling to work since I get this invalid hook call error when running. The signin class is below as well as the error.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import LockOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LockOutlined';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import {withFirebase} from "../Firebase";
import * as ROUTES from "../../constants/routes";
import {compose} from "recompose";

const SignInPage = () => (
    <div>
        <SignInForm />
    </div>
);

function Copyright() {
    return (
        <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" align="center">
            {'Copyright © '}
            <Link color="inherit" href="https://material-ui.com/">
                Your Company Here
            </Link>{' '}
            {new Date().getFullYear()}
            {'.'}
        </Typography>
    );
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        height: '100vh',
    },
    image: {
        backgroundImage: 'url(https://source.unsplash.com/random)',
        backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
        backgroundColor:
            theme.palette.type === 'light'
                ? theme.palette.grey[50]
                : theme.palette.grey[900],
        backgroundSize: 'cover',
        backgroundPosition: 'center',
    },
    paper: {
        margin: theme.spacing(8, 4),
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    avatar: {
        margin: theme.spacing(1),
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
    },
    form: {
        width: '100%', // Fix IE 11 issue.
        marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
    },
    submit: {
        margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2),
    },
}));

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    email: '',
    password: '',
    error: '',
}

class SignInFormBase extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {...INITIAL_STATE};
    }

    onSubmit = event => {
        const {email, password} = this.state;

        this.props.firebase
            .doSignInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then(() => {
                this.setState({...INITIAL_STATE});
                this.props.history.push(ROUTES.HOME);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.setState({error});
            });

        event.preventDefault();
    };

    onChange = event => {
        this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
    };

    render() {
        const classes = useStyles();

        return (
            <Grid container component="main" className={classes.root}>
                <CssBaseline />
                <Grid item xs={false} sm={4} md={7} className={classes.image} />
                <Grid item xs={12} sm={8} md={5} component={Paper} elevation={6} square>
                    <div className={classes.paper}>
                        <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
                            <LockOutlinedIcon />
                        </Avatar>
                        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                            Sign in
                        </Typography>
                        <form className={classes.form} noValidate>
                            <TextField
                                variant="outlined"
                                margin="normal"
                                required
                                fullWidth
                                id="email"
                                label="Email Address"
                                name="email"
                                autoComplete="email"
                                autoFocus
                            />
                            <TextField
                                variant="outlined"
                                margin="normal"
                                required
                                fullWidth
                                name="password"
                                label="Password"
                                type="password"
                                id="password"
                                autoComplete="current-password"
                            />
                            <Button
                                type="submit"
                                fullWidth
                                variant="contained"
                                className={classes.submit}
                            >
                                Sign In
                            </Button>
                            <Grid container>
                                <Grid item xs>
                                    <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                                        Forgot password?
                                    </Link>
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item>
                                    <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                                        {"Don't have an account? Sign Up"}
                                    </Link>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                            <Box mt={5}>
                                <Copyright />
                            </Box>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        )
    }
}

const SignInForm = compose(
    withRouter,
    withFirebase,
)(SignInFormBase);

export default SignInPage;

export {SignInForm};
```

I am getting the following error on the line

```
const classes = useStyles();
```

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

Comment: Check this https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html

Comment: You can't use hooks inside class based components I'm afraid - you could consider rewriting as a function component - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-hooks-classes-or-a-mix-of-both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must re-write the class based component trying to implement the hook `makeStyles` as a functional one. In your case the component that needs to be re-written is `SignInFormBase`. The question of how to convert a class based component to a function has been answered before here so you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59195850/reactjs-convert-class-components-to-functional-components) fore help on that.

Comment: Thank you! This actually helped a lot. I haven't really learned much about hooks in React yet, so based on  your answer I checked out some documentation about converting class components into hooks. I changed SignInFormBase into a hook rather than a class component and now I am getting the styling exactly as I wanted. Much easier to convert to a hook than I expected it to be as well, especially setting and updating the state.