# How can I convert functions in class-based component to functional components in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to convert my class-based React component to a functional component.
How should I convert functions like:

```
onFileUpload = async () => {

        const formData = new FormData();

        formData.append(
            "ImageData.File",
            this.state.selectedFile,
            this.state.selectedFile.name
        );



        fetch('/api/Image', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        }).then(resposne => resposne.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                this.setState({ uploadResult: "File " + data.fileName + " successfully uploaded." });
                this.getList();
            });

    };
```

The whole code comes here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YSSMTGkxzeH1R1V2rgQkwl1QwxnoXtuq/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Show the whole code.. I mean this particular file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reactjs convert class components to functional components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59195850/reactjs-convert-class-components-to-functional-components)

Comment: I add the whole code. You can see all. This is an upload component.

Answer (score 1):

```
const FuncComponent = () => {
    const onFileUpload = async () => {
       // do magic here
    }
    return <div />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to replace `this.state.selectedFile` with:

```
const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState() // and pass useState the initial state
```

When you need to update `selectedFile` you will call `setSelectedFile()` with the new data.

This is the same for `uploadResult`